# How to refer the class itself in Form mapping

Tags: scala, playframework

I have following case class and I want to create a form mapping function for it. The class uses objects of its own type. How can I write a mapping function for such scenario?

```
case class User (
  name:String,
  age:Int,
  female:Boolean,
  address:Address, //this is another case class of 3 Strings
  friends:List[User], //an object of its own type
  spouse:Option[User]
)
```

I have written this so far but do not know how to handle friends and spouse

```
val userForm = Form((mapping("name"->text,
    "age"->number,
    "female"->boolean,
    "address"->mapping("fullStreet"->text,
                        "county"->text,
                        "country"->text)(Address.apply)(Address.unapply),
    "friends"->list(???),
    "spouse"->optional(???)
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply))
```

Answer (score 0):

Often times types help you from shooting yourself in the foot. It is sometimes wise to reconsider what you're doing when you end up in these kinds of situations.

In this particular situation it is highly unlikely that you actually want an infinitely recursive structure where you also want the friends of the friends of the friends and so on, which will likely be your entire database. Also spouse will create a problem, because the spouse of somebodies' spouse is the same person, and so your data structure would never end. The same applies for friends. Of course I could consider you a friend and you could actually not consider me as a friend, but these situations are the exception to the rule :)

What you probably want to do is either one of two things:

1. Create a user trait and case class with just the base properties, so without friends and spouse, and use that trait as the base for your `User` case class and that case class as the underlying type for your `friends` and `spouse` .
2. Assign users ids and refer to a user in that fashion. `Friends` then just becomes a `Set[UserId]` and `spouse` a `Option[UserId]`.

Comment: appreciate your inputs in design. I am new to both Scala and Play and this is an exercise I picked from a book on Play/Java. I just couldn't the way to do the same thing in Scala/Play. Could you tell me how the problem could be solved from coding perspective in Scala/Play?

Comment: That totally depends on the design. I would definitely not go down the path you have taken with a User that has a User that has a User, ad infinitum. That is where the problem lies, thus that is where the answer lies. Pick a design that works, like the two suggestions I have given, and I am sure you will be able to continue coding.

Comment: @ManuChadha would be nice if you accepted my answer

Comment: Sorry, I like your answer but it doesn't address my question. There could be a problem in my design but what I need to know is whether it is possible to refer the same class in Scala ( I saw the implementation in Java so I guess it should be possible). Unless you can tell me that what I want to do isn't possible (not that I shouldn't do it), I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: Okay fair enough.